have language choice at login ubuntu 22.04
In an office I have several types of people who will log in on the same computer.
I have those who use the azerty keyboard, and those in qzerty.
To do this I can easily provide 2 physical keyboards next to the computer.
A user once logged in, can easily choose his language at the top right, he makes his selection.
But where this poses a problem for me is at the time of login.
He cannot use the keyboard for example in qwerty, because here it is in azerty. There is no choice possible.
Is this planned under ubuntu 22.04, as we could see under Debian 9 for example. A choice of keyboard language on the login page.
I thank you sincerely
Zizou

Is this feature working on Debian 9? Could you let us know if Debian 9 is using LightDM or GDM for login? Ubuntu uses GDM by default. If Debian is using Lightdm, then switching to LightDM in Ubuntu will fix the issue
